How to prevent docker compose from caching
So i just spent an hour making changes to a script and rerunning it and it kept giving me the same error.
Turns out that you can't just do docker compose up --build every time because it just runs some weird cached version of your script. You have to do docker compose rm -f first to clear the history.
Is there maybe a prettier way to run them both in one felt swoop (other than docker compose rm -f && docker compose up --build)? Or compose it without having it save stuff in memory?
Tried docker compose up --build --force-recreate too but that didn't work.
I'd like for it to build the container AND run the script right after (like docker compose up --build does), not just build it.

Does this answer your question? How to get docker-compose to always re-create containers from fresh images?

@xerx593 so looks like instead of docker compose rm -f && docker compose up --build you can do docker-compose build --no-cache, but that doesn't also run the script like "compose up" does. And docker-compose up build --no-cache gives an error "unknown flag: --no-cache"

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The thing I'd normally expect to happen is for docker compose up --build to re-run the image builder, a Dockerfile COPY command to notice the changed script, and from there to stop using anything cached.  I've seen several Compose setups that overwrite the image code with volume mounts, and those could cause problems like what you're describing.
